# cross domain at axios

Tags: ajax, django, reactjs, cors, axios

I am changing jquery ajax for axios and I not getting use axios with cross domain:

```
axios.get(myurl, {
            headers: { 'crossDomain': true },
        }).then(res => { 
            console.log(res);

        }).catch(error => {
            console.log('erro', error);
        })
```

My jquery code is working:

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   crossDomain: true,
   url:myurl,
   success: (res) => {},
   error: (fail) => {}     
})
```

The error: Request header field crossDomain is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 11):

"crossDomain" does not have to be in headers

```
axios.get(myurl, {
    crossDomain: true
}).then(res => { 
    console.log(res);
}).catch(error => {
    console.log('error', error);
})
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In my case @nuxtjs/proxy solved issue

https://nuxtjs.org/faq/http-proxy/

I inserted @nuxtjs/proxy in nuxt.config.js and edited proxy setting

I used api server and an rest api

```
proxy: {
'/api': {
  target: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080',
  pathRewrite: {
    '^/api' : '/api'
    },
},
'/zip': {
  target: 'http://zipcloud.ibsnet.co.jp',
  pathRewrite: {
    '^/zip' : '/api'
    }
}
}
```