# Using Axios as a Ping

Tags: javascript, axios

I have a web page is running on localhost. This web page has some JavaScript that runs when the page is loaded. I want to see if the web page can connect to the external internet.

I thought I would use [Axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), to see if I could hit Google. So, I tried the following:

```
axios.get('https://www.google.com')
  .then(function (res) {
    alert('Google found!');
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log(err);
    alert('Cannot find Google');
  })
;
```

When this code runs, I see the following error in my console window:

*XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.google.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.*

My question is, how can I use Axios to see if I can reach the internet?

Comment: Short answer is you can't unless remote site accepts head requests, and you only make a head request. Use a proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Axios cannot make cross domain requests, You can try using a cross domain library.
For example, jquery, zepto and so on.

Comment: Actually Axios can make cross domain requests, just need to include "crossDomain: true" in the request. See the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422494/cross-domain-at-axios

Comment: Axios can make cross-origin requests. You just have to enable CORS.