# Why isn’t fetch sending ORIGIN header in CORS mode?

Tags: typescript, cors, fetch

Like everyone else who attempts it, I am having trouble getting CORS to work.  My code is as follows:

```
fetch(url, {
      mode: 'cors',
      cache: 'no-cache',
      method: 'post',
      credentials: 'include',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
    });
```

Regardless of the URL, I do not get the `origin` header of the request showing in Chrome’s Network tab.

[image: screen-cap of Network tab]

And (“correctly”) the request fails with as `CORS Error`.

The `method` header isn’t there either, but I don’t know if that is part of the problem.

(Enragingly, this seems to work on Safari.)

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177387/caution-provisional-headers-are-shown-in-chrome-debugger

Comment: So this is a `POST` and requires preflighting if it is cross-domain i.e. `fetch` should be sending an `OPTIONS` request before making the post... Is it? You're also setting `credentials: 'include'` which piles on yet [more limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflight_requests_and_credentials). Are you sure you're ticking all the boxes?

Comment: Is that screen shot the OPTIONS request or the POST?

Comment: @spender — it is only sending the one request, no pre-flight, so does that mean that it does not realize it is supposed to be POST?  I am sure I am **not** ticking all the boxes, because it doesn’t work, but I don’t know which ones I missed.

Comment: @stringy05 — it is only sending the one request, no pre-flight.  Arrgggh.

Answer (score -1):

It was Amy who actually answered this.

The underlying problem is: the server is misconfigured.  I knew that and I was waiting for the server-guy to fix it.  In the meanwhile, I was trying to get the client side to work.

But, since I was getting bad headers back, Chrome decided to... well, act up, and only show [“provisional” headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42422494/cross-domain-at-axios) — which did not, for whatever reason, include the Origin header.

When Safari “worked”, it only worked in the sense of giving a sensible error response (“Not getting the right CORS headers back from the server”).  I don’t know what is keeping Chrome from doing this.

To figure this out, I had to download and learn Wireshark, then I had to make changes to some Bush-era Tomcat code under IntelliJ.  Arrrgghhh.

Comment: try this: set  chrome://flags/#out-of-blink-cors to disable, this should make Chrome display the pre-flight in the network tab.

Comment: Yeah, whenever I see the "provisional headers" thing, I switch to Fiddler.  It's the only way to see what's happening on the wire.

Comment: Yes. [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) are somewhat higher level means of doing this analysis and preferable to using WireShark.

Comment: @spender — thanks, I found WireShark to be fairly... gritty.

Comment: Yeh. It's overqualified for the job :)